# DNS lookups using dnsmasq on a different network

Tags: dnsmasq

I have a local network with a server running dnsmasq that acts as both a DHCP and DNS server. Let's call this network A. This is all working very well. I have it set up to not have a domain, so I can look up hosts with only a hostname, such as "alpha".

I also have some machines that travel together as a set. This set of machines has its own local network set up in a similar manner, so that one of the hosts runs dnsmasq to provide DHCP and DNS services. Let's call this network B. The machine that runs dnsmasq on network B is what I call the master. Again, I have network B set up so that I can look up hosts only with a hostname (no domain), such as "bravo".

The master of network B has an additional network dongle that is occasionally used to connect to network A. It gets an address through DHCP on network A, while still connected to network B and serving addresses and DHCP to hosts on network B. Hosts on network B can access the internet through this connection by enabling IP masquerading on the firewall on the master of network B.

My problem is this: how do I set up dnsmasq so that I can, when logged into a machine on network B, find machines on network A? I can find the hosts if I use their IP addresses, but I'd much rather use their domainless name instead. I tried to add "server=<IPv4_address_of_Network_A_DHCP_host>" (with the real IP address of that server instead of this name) to the dnsmasq configuration on network B but it didn't work. I don't generally need to access the hosts on network B from the hosts on network A. I suspect the problem here is the lack of domain on both networks, but I really don't want to set up domains on either of these networks if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed to comment out both the "domain-needed" and the "bogus-priv" lines in the dnsmasq configuration on the master of network B.